# Prove that cardinality of set of all functions from set A to set B is |B|^|A|?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose set A is {a1,a2} and set B be {b1,b2}
now for set of all functions from set A to set B , a1 has two choices b1 or b2 and a2 also has 2 choices b2 or b1. Hence total are 2*2 = 4 .But i want proper mathematical proof

I found this proof but i couldnt understand the (2.3)

|Cm,n| is the cardinaliy of set of all functions

Without loss of generality, assume A = {1, 2, . . . , m} and
B = {1, 2, . . . , n}.
2.2 A function f : A → B is uniquely specified by the m-tuple (f (1), f (2), . . . , f (m)).
2.3 Thus, there exists a bijection from |Cm,n| to B × B × · · · × B| m times.
2.4 Hence, |Cm,n| = | B × B × · · · × B| m times.
2.5 By product rule, this cardinality is equal to |B|^m = n^m.

Comment: What is $C_{m,n}$?

Comment: sorry ,|Cm,n| is the cardinaliy of set of all functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case when $A$ is empty is easy: there is one map from the empty set to any other set.

Now suppose that the statement is true for sets having less elements than $A$, which is not empty.

Choose $x\in A$ and consider $A'=A\setminus\{x\}$. We know that there are $|B|^{|A'|}$ maps $A'\to B$, by the induction hypothesis.

Given $f'\colon A'\to B$, how many maps $A\to B$ can it be the restriction of?